# Connect to XMPP server using xmpp.js in the browser

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmpp

I'm trying to run a test using a local xmpp server in the browser.

```
import { client } from '@xmpp/client';

const xmpp = client({
  service: 'xmpp://localhost:5222/',
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass',
});

xmpp.start().catch(err => {
  console.error('start failed', err);
});
```

But I get the following error:

> No compatible connection method found.

From what I've read, the browser expects a websocket connection instead of an xmpp connection.

The `xmpp.js` documentation says that it supports websockets as well, but I'm not sure what I have to change in order to successfully connect. Do I have to add WS support to my XMPP server?

Comment: FYI for anyone coming across this while using Electron, that error means you're running the XMPP code in the renderer process (only supports websockets) when it should be in the background process (Node supports xmpp and websockets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you would have to change your `service` URI - both protocol as well as port part. As per [xmpp.js client documentation](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/tree/master/packages/client) you should use:

```
service: 'ws://localhost:5280/xmpp-websocket',
```

Exact path may be xmpp-server dependent (i.e. `xmpp-websocket` may not be needed) - please check your server's documentation.

Comment: This was it, but I ended up switching to Strophe in the end.

Comment: @norbert How do I load strophe? When I copy the strophe.js file into my project folder and run the echobot example, I get an import error. Can you point me to a tutorial or how to setup strophe ?